# Searching a byte array

Tags: vb.net

Basically I am searching a byte array in VB.NET, with this code:

```
For i As Integer = 0 To message.Length - 1
    If message(i) = Asc(ControlChars.Cr) Then
        If message(i + 1) = Asc(ControlChars.Lf) Then
            If message(i + 2) = Asc(ControlChars.Cr) Then
                If message(i + 3) = Asc(ControlChars.Lf) Then
                    start = i + 4 ' take into account the above characters
                    Exit For
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End If
Next

Dim length As Integer = message.Length - start
```

I was wondering if there was a better way of doing this? I tried doing something like this:

```
start = message.IndexOf({ControlChars.CrLf, ControlChars.CrLf})
```

but that returns -1.

Also, is there a better way to strip off bytes from an array of bytes, as I have this:

```
Dim text(message.Length - start) As Byte
Dim position As Integer = 0
For i As Integer = start To message.Length - 1
    text(position) = message(i)
    position = position + 1
Next
```

Comment: Is this an array of bytes or characters? Can you explain what _exactly_ you are trying to achieve here? Remove all line breaks?

Comment: This is all byte arrays, I need to trim off the bytes between the beginning and the first location where the pair of CrLFs are found.

Comment: `Dim message_as_string = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(message)`. Then use `IndexOf`.

Comment: Unfortunately the byte arrays can be as large as 3MB or more.

Comment: Well, it is obviously a byte array representing a _string_. What are you trying to do with this string? And what _encoding_ is the string in, as `ControlChars.Lf` and such may not be what you think they are.

Comment: The byte arrays are pure 8 bit characters as received over the internet. The part that I wanted to trim off are the headers which I don't want, and the rest contains gzipped textual data.

Comment: 8 bit characters in what encoding? How are you getting them?

Comment: 8 bit and it's read from a sslstream